# How to add a customized TFS build 's `summary information` message?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, workflow-activity, build-process-template

I'm writing a customized activity for TFS build process workflow, e.g. guideline [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1IYXC.png).

In my C# CodeActivity .Execute() method, I want to output my text to the TFS build 's `summary information` as the snapshot below.

How can I do that?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should to use the `CustomSummaryInformation` object to display the summary message. Here is the code. Hope it helps.

```
 protected override void Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
 {
    var summaryReport = new CustomSummaryInformation()
    {
    Message = "Your message",
    SectionPriority = 0,
    SectionHeader = "Header Name",
    SectionName = "Section Name",
    };
    context.Track(summaryReport);
}
```

Comment: In my case (.NET 4.6.1) - I had to use `System.Activities.Tracking.CustomTrackingRecord` instead of `CustomSummaryInformation`